# Cordova/Phonegap GCM and Airpush

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-2.0.0

Ok i have the gcm plugin from marknutter/GCM-Cordova and the airpush sdk installed...
https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Both work Seperatly but when combined i get an error and app crashes... logcat info...

```
11-26 20:43:31.475: D/webviewglue(1847): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a3a5c88
11-26 20:43:32.655: D/BUGSENSE(1847): {"data": [], "error": null}
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847): java.lang.NullPointerException: println eeds a message
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847): at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847):    at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847):    at school.is.in.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:63)
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:179)
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 20:43:32.675: D/BugSenseHandler(1847):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-GCMIntentService-4]
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at school.is.in.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:63)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:179)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 20:43:32.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

From the little knowledge that i have of android it looks like the message doesn't have any data and that crashes apps... i've checked the sent message from the server to google gcm server looks good... my question is how to tell if airpush is consuming the data before hand..

I may be way off... someone point me in the write direction...

Thanks roger....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems stepping away a little bit brought me to my senses and read the console data.... and it says it was the logger creating the problem... so never mind...

Comment: Don't use airpush - They are a scam - they never pay (to me and to 2 of my friends) or pay much less due to all sorts of reasons they make up.. (google it)